# Morse Interpreter-Microphone Problem

Tags: arduino-nano

I am working on a morse interpreter. I can now use light-sensor and a regular key as input device and want to add a mic to the system. I recieve the input convert it to text and show it on nokia 5110 lcd. And also whilst input, an led and a buzzer turns on and off simultaneously. When I use mic the led works just as it should but I do not get any correct input to the lcd. I attached Out and Gnd pins of mic just as I would attach the key and vcc to 5v.

The following is the code which I use

```
#define RST 12
#define CE  11
#define DC  10
#define DIN  9
#define CLK  8

#include "font.h";



unsigned long signal_len,t1,t2; //time for which button is pressed
int inputPin=2; //input pin for push button
int ledPin=4; //output pin for LED
String code=""; //string in which one alphabet is stored

void LcdWriteString(char *characters){
  while(*characters) LcdWriteCharacter(*characters++);
}

void LcdWriteCharacter(char character){
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) LcdWriteData(ASCII[character-0x20][i]);
LcdWriteData(0x00);
}
void LcdWriteData(byte dat)
{
  digitalWrite(DC, HIGH); //DC pin is low for commands
  digitalWrite(CE, LOW);
  shiftOut(DIN, CLK, MSBFIRST, dat); //transmit serial data
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);
}
void LcdWriteCmd(byte cmd)
{
  digitalWrite(DC, LOW); //DC pin is low for commands
  digitalWrite(CE, LOW);
  shiftOut(DIN, CLK, MSBFIRST, cmd); //transmit serial data
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);


}
void setup()

{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLUP); //internal pullup resistor is used to simplify the circuit
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);

    pinMode(RST, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RST, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RST, HIGH);

  LcdWriteCmd(0x21);  // LCD extended commands
  LcdWriteCmd(0xA9);  // set LCD Vop (contrast)
  LcdWriteCmd(0x04);  // set temp coefficent
  LcdWriteCmd(0x14);  // LCD bias mode 1:40
  LcdWriteCmd(0x20);  // LCD basic commands
  LcdWriteCmd(0x0C);  // LCD normal video


  for(int i=0;i<504;i++)LcdWriteData(0x00);
}

void loop()
{
NextDotDash:
  while (digitalRead(inputPin) == HIGH) {}
  t1 = millis();                            //time at button press
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);               //LED on while button pressed
  while (digitalRead(inputPin) == LOW) {}
  t2 = millis();                            //time at button release
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);                //LED off on button release
  signal_len = t2 - t1;                     //time for which button is pressed
  if (signal_len > 50)                      //to account for switch debouncing
  {
    code += readio();                       //function to read dot or dash
  }
  while ((millis() - t2) < 500)           //if time between button press greater than 0.5sec, skip loop and go to next alphabet
  {     
    if (digitalRead(inputPin) == LOW)
    {
      goto NextDotDash;
    }
  }
  convertor();                          //function to decipher code into alphabet
}
char readio()
{
  if (signal_len < 150 && signal_len > 20)
  {
    return '.';                        //if button press less than 0.6sec, it is a dot
  }
  else if (signal_len > 150)
  {
    return '-';                        //if button press more than 0.6sec, it is a dash
  }
}
void convertor()
{
  static String letters[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
                             ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "E"
                            };
  int i = 0;
  if (code == ".-.-.-")
  {
    Serial.print(".");        //for break
    LcdWriteCharacter(".");
  }
  else
  {
    while (letters[i] != "E")  //loop for comparing input code with letters array
    {
      if (letters[i] == code)
      {
        Serial.print(char('A' + i));
        LcdWriteCharacter(char('A' + i));
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (letters[i] == "E")
    {
      Serial.println("");  //if input code doesn't match any letter, error
      LcdWriteCharacter("");
    }
  }
  code = "";                            //reset code to blank string
}
```

Comment: print the `signal_len`

Comment: Please don't use `goto`, unless you really really need it. Using this can lead to big problems. There is a reason, why it is seldomly used in C/C+. You can just put the `convertor()` inside the if, where the `goto` is, and add a break after it.

Comment: Depending on what "mic" you use, you may also need a pre-amplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I attached Out and Gnd pins of mic just as I would attach the key and
>   vcc to 5v.

This can't work. Unlike the key, the microphone is an analog device that
will output a continuously varying analog signal. If you expose it to a
pure tone it will output a sine wave. If you sing a note in front of it,
it will pick not only the sine but also a lot of harmonics. In any case,
it will also pick the ambient noise.

What you need to do is somehow determine the amplitude of the sound
signal, then compare that to some threshold in order to decide whether
the amplitude is high enough to be considered “on”. You could use a
diode-based peak detector and a comparator. Doing all this in code is
kind of tricky. You may want to take a look at this [sound-level meter
sketch](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/e693799f58a545ca89a2), but note that a software peak detection could be
simpler than the true-RMS intensity detection implemented in that
sketch.